# Android: layout with imageView re-sizing buttons wrongly

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I have a layout problem, I want an image to be in the middle of two buttons. So I created the two buttons and defined a weightSum of 1. I then set the weight of the two buttons to .40 and the image to .20 so that the image would be a small logo in the middle of the two buttons. The problem is the image is stretched out and the buttons are pushed aside.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".40"
    android:background="@drawable/custombuttonred"
    android:text="@string/clear"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".20"
    android:src="@drawable/imageid" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonBackspace"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".40"
    android:background="@drawable/custombuttonred"
    android:text="@string/backspace"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: is it in a linear layout? if yes, what is it's orientation? if vertical, you should not use fill_parent for layout_height

Comment: Can you list the enclosing View as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had also faced the same issue. I used the button insted of ImageView and set background image to it.

Answer (score 0):

This code: http://pastebin.com/3P9BWEcQ

Works well for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use dp for resizing the image for both height & width.Say if you ar image is in original size of 400px width & 200 px height,just resize according to the screen size i.e if you are device in which you are testing currently could only hold half of the image size then android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="100dp".If you follow resizing using dp image will get resized to both the smaller & larger device you are using.Make sure that when you have any larger devices screen than the one currently you are testing,just try to have the image as large as possible to get the best results.